# React - update next state and redirect in reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Am new to React and was trying out react from few days now. Just wanted to know how will i update a new state and redirect to new route in react. I was trying out something like this:

```
Object.assign({}, state, {client: action.client});
Router.browserHistory.push('/edit-client?id='+action.client.client_id);
```

But noticed by component was not updated with new state.

**reduce.js**

```
const reducer = (state = initial, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {    
    case EDIT_CLIENT:
      Object.assign({}, state, {client: action.client});
      Router.browserHistory.push('/edit-client?id='+action.client.client_id);

    default:
      return state;
  }

};

export default reducer;
```

**action dispatcher**

```
export const editClient = (client_id) => dispatch => {
    axios.get(conf.getWebServiceUrl('clients/edit?client_id='+client_id), {headers: conf.getHeaders()})
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
        return response.data.message;
      })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(editClientConst(response))
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error.bind(err);
      })
  };
```

**ACTIONS**

```
const editClientConst = (client) => ({type: EDIT_CLIENT, client});
```

Comment: Can you add which version of react-router you use and how have you configured your routes

Comment: reducers should be pure functions. Side effects should be performed in action creators.

Comment: the reason why this doesn't work is that you perform routing after function returns (code after return statement is not reachable).

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri react router version is 3.0.0

Comment: @marzelin ignore the return statement. I forgot to remove that part. I was trying something like this without a return

case EDIT_CLIENT:
      Object.assign({}, state, {client: action.client});
      Router.browserHistory.push('/edit-client?id='+action.client.client_id);

Comment: @marzelin updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redirect inside the render function, and trigger the state/authentication by props in the reducer

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';

render() {
    if(this.state.changeClient) {
        return (
            <Redirect to="/myroute" />
        );
    }
```

Comment: i get minification error when i redirect inside render function.

Code snippet. Am i missing something? 

if(Object.keys(this.props.client).length > 0){
        var myroute = '/edit-client?id=' + this.props.client.client_id;
        return (
            <Redirect to={myroute} />
        );

    }

Comment: the redirect is expecting a route, and you are passing an object, that doesent seem to work very well, instead myroute try to use this 
`<Redirect to={"/edit-client?id=${this.props.client.client_id}"}`
also change the apostrophe inside Redirect to grave accent so ecmascript ${} feature works fine

Comment: `if(Object.keys(this.props.client).length > 0){
        browserHistory.push('/edit-client?id=' + this.props.client.client_id);
    }`

This worked for me